# JMenuItem action performed trouble

Tags: java, user-interface

I am having trouble implementing JMenuItem. I want my JMenuItem,"Pythagoras" in this case to make a tree, which means if a user clicks pythagoras, I want to make display a tree. I have a class called PythagorasTree which draws the tree. I am having difficulty connecting PythagorasTree class with JMenuItem. I am new in GUI. Any Help will be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuExp extends PythagorasTree{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Computer Graphics HW");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.pack();

        // Creating MenuBar
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        // Creating Menu
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);

        //creating item inside File
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file.add(exit);

        JMenuItem pythagoras = new JMenuItem("Pythagoras");
        file.add(pythagoras);

        class exitaction implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        class pythagorasAction implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*
                 * Do something here
                 * 
                 */
            }
        }
        exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `PythagorasTree` draw the tree? On the console? into a JPanel? without knowing how this class works it's impossible to tell you how to integrate it with the menu. In principle, using the ActionListener (don't forget to add it to the pythagoras-JMenuItem) is the right way, although the definition of the classes within a method will now compile.

Comment: It draws into a JPanel. All I want to do is, when the user clicks the JMenuItem (Pythagoras) a free should be drawn.